# How do I insert a template to write code on with intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

From this screen
[image]

I cannot figure out how to get a basic template or scratchpad or whatever it's so that I can start writing code in java. Any help would be appreciated.

---

update

Ok, I did that and got this[image]

Then it brought me back to the same window
[image]

Comment: See comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created an "empty project".

Try to create a new project *File -> New -> Project* and select `Java` as the project type.

then, you should see a `src` folder which is blue. Right click from here to create your first java class.

Comment: Drill down now on `practise3` in the project view - find the folder marked `src`. From there, right-click `src` and make a java class.